# Plot colormap to unique labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm hoping to map varying colours to a quiver plot determined by the associated label. Using below, unique items are defined by the col `Label`. I'm hoping to plot the same color for each unique item in `Label`.

Note: The amount of unique items may vary across df's so I don't want to hardcode colors. I'm hoping to take any amount of unique labels and pass a colormap.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('XYUV'))
labels = df['X'].apply(lambda x: random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])) 
df['Label'] = labels

X = df['X'] 
Y = df['Y'] 
U = df['U'] 
V = df['V'] 

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-10, 30)
ax.set_ylim(-10, 30)

color_labels = df['Label'].unique()
col_values = sns.color_palette('Set2')
color_map = dict(zip(color_labels, col_values))

ax.quiver(X, Y, (U-X), (V-Y), angles = 'xy', scale_units = 'xy', scale = 1, color = color_map)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list of colors for each vector with

```
colors = [color_map[label] for label in df['Label'].values]
```

With the `colors`,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches


data = np.vstack((np.random.randint(0,10,size=(25, 4)),
                  np.random.randint(10,20,size=(25, 4)),
                  np.random.randint(20,30,size=(25, 4)),
                  np.random.randint(30,40,size=(25, 4))))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('XYUV'))
df['Label'] = np.repeat(np.array(['A','B','C','D'])[:,None],25)

X = df['X'] 
Y = df['Y'] 
U = df['U'] 
V = df['V'] 

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-10, 40)
ax.set_ylim(-10, 40)

color_labels = df['Label'].unique()
col_values = sns.color_palette('Set2')
color_map = dict(zip(color_labels, col_values))
colors = [color_map[label] for label in df['Label'].values]

ax.quiver(X, Y, (U-X), (V-Y), angles = 'xy', scale_units = 'xy', scale = 1, color = colors,)
ax.legend(handles=[mpatches.Patch(color=v,label=k) for k,v in color_map.items()])
```

[image: output]